# how to use json array in FusionCharts?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

I am using fusion chart in my application.I am taking json array from servlet to javascript.

Code :

```
 var customerCountList=response.sharecountlist;
 FusionCharts.ready(function(){
                            var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
                                type: "column3d",
                                renderAt: "spraybookerCount-bar",
                                width: "500",
                                height: "300",
                                dataFormat: "json",
                                dataSource: {
                                    "chart": {
                                        "caption": "Revenue for last year",
                                        "palettecolors": "e44a00",
                                        "subCaption": "Harry's SuperMart",
                                        "xAxisName": "refvalue",
                                        "yAxisName": "['viewcount']",

                                        "theme": "carbon"
                                    },
                                    "data"://here i want to use response.sharecountlist
                                }

                            });
                            revenueChart.render("spraybookerCount-bar");
                        });
```

here **sharecountlist** is sharecountlist==[{"viewcount":99,"refvalue":"Guest"},{"viewcount":4,"refvalue":"facebook"},{"viewcount":2,"refvalue":"friend"}].

**sharecountlist** is dynamic ,so how can I use this **sharecountlist** in place of data in above code. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: please anyone give solution

Comment: if there is no solution then is there is any other charts like morris are availabe to put above json data on bar chart?

Comment: did you find the answer?